# Symfony 2: AvalancheImagineBundle - Unable to find controller "imagine.controller:filter"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

I get this error using AvalancheImagine bundle for generating thumbnails:

```
Unable to find controller "imagine.controller:filter".
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException
```

The bundle is registered in `AppKernel.php`. The routing and config yml files are updated, but still I get this error when I load the asset's url in dev environment.

The following output in dev mode:

```
    protected function createController($controller)
    {
        if (false === strpos($controller, '::')) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Unable to find controller "%s".', $controller));
        }
        list($class, $method) = explode('::', $controller, 2);

at ControllerResolver ->createController ('imagine.controller:filter')
in E:\workspace\***\app\cache\dev\classes.php at line 5297  -+
at ControllerResolver ->getController (object(Request))
in E:\workspace\***\src\Inhouse\MainBundle\Event\BeforeControllerActionListener.php at line 32  -+
```

My `composer.json`:

```
"avalanche123/imagine-bundle": "dev-master",
```

Comment: What does the error says in dev mode ?

Comment: @j0k - updated question - it seems like a incompatibility with my symfony version 2.1.4

Comment: What did you define in your composer.json to retrieve AvalancheImagineBundle?

Comment: Try using `v2.1` instead of `dev-master`, as described in the github readme.

Comment: @j0k - ok but how can i force reinstall the package to the correct version? if I delete from composer.lock - no effect

Comment: Removing `composer.lock`, `vendor` dir and launch `composer install`?

Comment: @j0k - done reinstall avalanche v2.1 but I got the same issue :|

Comment: search for "imagine.controller" in the code. check your configuration file maybe it's misspelled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using your own controller?

if so you should have:

```
parameters:
    imagine.controller.class: Company\AnyBundle\Controller\ImagineController
```

maybe you forgot the `.class` ?